# Ansible - ENTRYPOINT with relative path

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-tower

We are able to run the docker container locally with docker file having relative path in `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
USER user1

WORKDIR /home/user1

ADD script.sh $HOME/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
```

---

When the same docker image(of above docker file) is launched from ansible tower using below task:

```
- name: Run docker container
  command: docker run --rm -e arg={{value}} 111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam:v.1
```

---

We get file not found error for `script.sh`

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Does it work in a less complex environment, for instance directly `docker run` the same image without Ansible?  If you get a debug shell in a container based on the image, is the script where you expect?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it runs without ansible

Comment: a) you have to quote your command string since it contains a jinja placeholder b) Don't use `command` for this but the [`docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html)

Comment: @Zeitounator Do you mean somthing like this? `command: "docker run --rm -e arg={{value}} 111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam:v.1"` In debug I see them getting resolved without double quotes

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean. Which version of ansible are you using ? It should only be allowed and ^work' with old versions...

Comment: @Zeitounator ansible 2.3

Comment: That's old. I don't remember exactly but `docker_container` might be called `docker` in that version... And then the var interpolation is not an issue and should not influence the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: @Zeitounator `docker` module is requiring `pip install docekr-py` which I cannot do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your entrypoint to use the full path to the script:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/user1/script.sh"]
```

Comment: Yes it worked this way... but why we need full path, when using ansible?

Comment: `environment:
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{ansible_env.HOME}}/go/bin"` this does not help from ansible

Comment: Why do we need full path, when we go with ansible?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure why you are seeing the different behaviour. I cannot reproduce it, possibly because there are some parts of your Dockerfile (and maybe build steps) missing in the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Vars   {{ playbook_dir }}->Full path to playbook
or:  {{ role_path}} ->The path to the dir of the currently running role
Could help.